# How do you add a link to a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Before anyone jumps on me. I am a network admin (CCNP) IA/CND (CISSP) type. I state that to let everyone know where I'm coming from. This maybe the easiest question but how do you add an onclick to buttons listed below and have it go to say...ancestry.com. I think I'll have other buttons go to other sites as well.  Building my first website Family Xmas gift and learning as I go. Found a template site and  having a heck of a time.

```js
/* Try This*/
$(".hover").mouseleave(
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500);
 .snip1564 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #029ebe;
  border-top: 6px solid #029ebe;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 46px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 34px;
  margin: 15px 40px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.snip1564:before,
.snip1564:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -6px;
  content: "";
  height: 46px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 46px;
  border: 6px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
.snip1564:before {
  right: -23px;
  border-left-color: #029ebe;
  border-bottom-color: #029ebe;
}
.snip1564:after {
  left: -23px;
  border-right-color: #029ebe;
  border-top-color: #029ebe;
}
.snip1564:hover,
.snip1564.hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.snip1564:hover:before,
.snip1564.hover:before,
.snip1564:hover:after,
.snip1564.hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
/* Try This*/

body {
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="snip1564">ancestry.com</button>
<button class="snip1564 hover">Facebook</button>
<button class="snip1564">Youtube</button>
<button class="snip1564">Send a happy Holidays greeting</button>
```

Comment: You want to use anchor (link) tags, not buttons. `<a class="snip1564" href="http://url_here">Text here</a>`

Comment: You're using jQuery syntax but didn't include it in your example or tag your question with it

Comment: [Here's a simple example of a link.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpYrEK)

Comment: A `<button>` can contain any other HTML, including `<a href="">...</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways, make a hyperlink that looks like a button, or make a button w/ a click handler that changes the page.

You will need some css to define how a button looks and assign it to a class

```
<a href='http://www.ancestry.com' class='button'>Ancestry</a>
```

or

```
<button class="snip1564" onclick='window.location="http://www.ancestry.com"'>
  ancestry.com
</button>
```

edit: here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qa0kco9b/1/